# Tkinter textvariable does not work in a secondary window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Because when I use textvariable from a secondary window called from a command in another window the variable.set () is not reflected in that secondary window.

example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def test():
    ven=tk.Tk()
    v1=tk.StringVar()
    v1.set('TEST')
    print(v1.get())
    tk.Label(ven, textvariable=v1).pack()
    ven.mainloop()

win=tk.Tk()
tk.Button(text='BOTON',command=test).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

In this case the message 'TEST' set through 'set' is not registered in the Label textvariable..

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you have several `Tk` instances running simultaneously. Tkinter is based on the the Tk gui framework which is a tcl library. Therefore each `Tk` instance is not just a window, it's also a tcl interpreter, therefore, when you have several `Tk` instances, they cannot share `StrinVar` because the value of the `StrinVar` is defined in one interpreter (here `win`) which does not communicate with the other one (`ven`).

To avoid this kind of issue, just don't use several `Tk` instances, use `Toplevel` windows instead:

```
import tkinter as tk

def test():
    ven = tk.Toplevel(win)
    v1 = tk.StringVar(win)
    v1.set('TEST')
    print(v1.get())
    tk.Label(ven, textvariable=v1).pack()


win = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(text='BOTON', command=test).pack()
win.mainloop()
```